# Vibration not ocurring on React-Native Android Device when unplugged

Tags: android, react-native, android-vibration

```
import { Vibration } from 'react-native';

const handleThrottledShake = () => {
  Vibration.vibrate(500);
  console.log('ran vibration');
}
```

I'm currently developing a react-native app and running into some trouble. When connecting my phone via a usb cable, vibration works. However, when I unplug it, everything else works, including `console.log('ran vibration');` but no vibration actually occurs. [The docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/vibration) say  say that vibration doesn't work on an emulator, but I'm using a physical device (OnePlus6), so I don't think that's the issue.

Does anybody have any ideas on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue! Had nothing to do with React Native, it was actually my phone. My phone was on battery saver when unplugged, which apparently disabled the vibration.

Answer (score 0):

@Oliver Ullman please close the issue if there is no issue left related to this.